# Lumen Call to undefined function request() TymonsDesign

Tags: lumen

Using `Lumen` for the first time, I have installed it and following the [Tymondesign documentation](https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/lumen-installation/) for the `JWT authentication`. After everything is done I am trying to login to the endpoint `http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/login` but I am getting error that `Call to undefined function App\\Http\\Controllers\\request()`. Not only the `auth()` function also not working here.

> AuthController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    //

    /**
     * Create a new AuthController instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login']]);
    }

    /**
     * Get a JWT via given credentials.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function login()
    {
        $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);

        if (! $token = auth()->attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
        }

        return $this->respondWithToken($token);
    }

    /**
     * Get the authenticated User.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function me()
    {
        return response()->json(auth()->user());
    }

    /**
     * Log the user out (Invalidate the token).
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function logout()
    {
        auth()->logout();

        return response()->json(['message' => 'Successfully logged out']);
    }

    /**
     * Refresh a token.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function refresh()
    {
        return $this->respondWithToken(auth()->refresh());
    }

    /**
     * Get the token array structure.
     *
     * @param  string $token
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    protected function respondWithToken($token)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'access_token' => $token,
            'token_type' => 'bearer',
            'expires_in' => auth()->factory()->getTTL() * 60
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, `request()` helper is not included within the Lumen framework, you can access it this way:

```php
app('request');
```

or create a helper function for both `request()` and `auth()`:

```php
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Factory as AuthFactory;

if (! function_exists('request')) {
    /**
     * Get an instance of the current request or an input item from the request.
     *
     * @param  array|string|null  $key
     * @param  mixed  $default
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Request|string|array
     */
    function request($key = null, $default = null)
    {
        if (is_null($key)) {
            return app('request');
        }

        if (is_array($key)) {
            return app('request')->only($key);
        }

        $value = app('request')->__get($key);

        return is_null($value) ? value($default) : $value;
    }
}

if (! function_exists('auth')) {
    /**
     * Get the available auth instance.
     *
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Factory|\Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard|\Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
     */
    function auth($guard = null)
    {
        if (is_null($guard)) {
            return app(AuthFactory::class);
        }

        return app(AuthFactory::class)->guard($guard);
    }
}
```